# CSS padding-bottom not working

Tags: css, padding

I'm currently trying to add some simple padding to the bottom of my testimonial element, so that it doesn't end right after the text.

It seems that no matter what value I enter in padding or padding-bottom, the bottom padding expands a set amount. I'm wondering how to fix this so it displays padding that is specific to the value I set.

```css
/****
GENERAL
****/

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: black;
}

html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0 0 120px;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
    
}

a, a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
}

a:hover {
    color: #009999;
}

.divide {
    width: 75%;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    margin: 20px auto;
    
}

/****
NAVIGATION
****/

.navigation {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.navigation li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
}

.navigation li a {
    padding: 8px 10px;
    display: block;
}

.submenu {
    position: relative
}

.sub-hover {
    position: absolute;
    width: 106.42px;
    display: none;
}

.sub-hover a {
    font-size: 1em;
}

.submenu:hover ~ .sub-hover,
.sub-hover:hover {
    display: block;
    background-color: rgba(38, 12, 12, 0.04);
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5%;
}

/****
LOGO
****/

.circle {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 90px;
    width: 90px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    clear: both;
}

/****
IMAGE SLIDER
****/

.main-gallery {
    background-color: rgba(38, 12, 12, 0.03);
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 450px;
    clear: both;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

/****
TESTIMONIAL
****/

.testimonial {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 0 5%;
    background-color: rgba(50, 173, 140, 0.82);
}

/****
SOCIAL
****/

.insta {
    height: 50px;
    width: 90%;
    background-color: blue;
    margin: 10px auto;
}



/****
FOOTER
****/

.footer {
    background-color: grey;
    height: 100px;
    clear: both;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

.footer p {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/skeleton.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  </head>

  <body>
  
          <ul class="navigation six columns offset-by-three">
              <li><a href="#" style="color: #009999">HOME</a></li>
              <li><a href="portfolio.html" class="submenu">PORTFOLIO</a>
                  <div class="sub-hover">
                    <a href="portfolio/photo.html">Photos</a>
                    <a href="portfolio/physical.html">Physical</a>
                    <a href="portfolio/write.html">Write</a>
                    <a href="portfolio/studies.html">Studies</a>
                  </div>
              </li>
              <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
              <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
          </ul>
      
      <div id="logo">
        <div class="circle">
        </div>
      </div>
    
    <div class="main-gallery eleven columns offset-by-half">
          <div id="main-images">
            <img src=""/>
            <img src=""/>
            <img src=""/>
            <img src=""/>
          </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="testimonial">
        <div class="test-text">          
            <p><b>Joe Blogs</b></p>
            <p>Distinguished Person</p>
            <p><i>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas et orci sit amet nibh aliquam auctor eu eget turpis. Quisque quis leo lacus. Etiam vitae magna eu arcu gravida tincidunt. Ut consectetur mi id enim."</i></p>
        </div>
    </div>
      
    <div class="divide"></div>
      
    <div class="insta">
        
        
    </div>
      
    <div class="footer twelve columns">
        <p>Jacob Riman Design</p>
      
    </div>
    
  </body>
  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that having the last set of text in .testimonial in a paragraph tag, it was inserting a line break. So simply took that away and now it seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 2):

How padding shorthand works....

default declaration of padding looks like this:

```
padding-top: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-left: 10px;
```

You can abbreviate that and apply padding to all sides equally:

```
padding: 10px;
```

You can abbreviate a little less and apply different values to top and bottom, and right and left.

This equates to `padding: top/bottom right/left;`

```
padding: 10px 20px;
```

You can use full abbreviations to apply different values to each of the 4 sides independently:

This equates to `padding: top right bottom left;` or:

```
padding: 10px 20px 5px 20px;
```

In your CSS you have no top or bottom padding applied to the `testimonial` class, you only have right/left padding applied:

```
.testimonial {
    padding: 0 5%;
}
```

You basically have (pseudo code as example):

```
.testimonial {
    padding: top=0 right=5% bottom=0 left=5%;
}
```

If you want a the same padding all the way around, remove the first 0 in the property:

```
.testimonial {
    padding: 5%;
}
```

If you want a similar top/bottom padding, then merely adjust the padding property to add top/bottom values:

```
.testimonial {
    padding: 10% 5%;
}
```

If you want *different* padding on the top and bottom, then adjust the padding property to add all the values:

```
.testimonial {
    padding: 0 5% 10% 5%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't currently have padding on the bottom of the testimonial div.

```
.testimonial {
   clear: both;
   display: block;
   margin: 10px 0;
   padding: 1% 5%;
   background-color: rgba(50, 173, 140, 0.82);
}
```

Change the padding to the above ... padding: 1% 5%; or to target specifically the bottom ... padding 0 5% 1%; ... do that and you should be good to go, unless I'm misunderstanding your question. Good luck!

Comment: Oh yes I know, I've taken it away as it wasn't doing anything.
changing the padding to '5px 5%', did exactly the same as changing it to '9px 5%'.

It seems to be something else that is causing the issue.

Comment: Which browser are you using, could perhaps be an issue I'm having with chrome?

Comment: Also using Chrome, so not sure. Did you try to change the padding to what I have above?

Comment: Yes.

I figured it out, seemed that having the last set of text in .testimonial as a <p>, it was inserting a line break. So simply took that away and now it seems to be working fine.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any bottom padding. Changing to `padding: 10px 5%` adds 10px padding to the top and bottom, 5% to the left and right.

```css
/****
GENERAL
****/

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: black;
}

html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0 0 120px;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
    
}

a, a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
}

a:hover {
    color: #009999;
}

.divide {
    width: 75%;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    margin: 20px auto;
    
}

/****
NAVIGATION
****/

.navigation {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.navigation li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
}

.navigation li a {
    padding: 8px 10px;
    display: block;
}

.submenu {
    position: relative
}

.sub-hover {
    position: absolute;
    width: 106.42px;
    display: none;
}

.sub-hover a {
    font-size: 1em;
}

.submenu:hover ~ .sub-hover,
.sub-hover:hover {
    display: block;
    background-color: rgba(38, 12, 12, 0.04);
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5%;
}

/****
LOGO
****/

.circle {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 90px;
    width: 90px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    clear: both;
}

/****
IMAGE SLIDER
****/

.main-gallery {
    background-color: rgba(38, 12, 12, 0.03);
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 450px;
    clear: both;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

/****
TESTIMONIAL
****/

.testimonial {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 10px 5%;
    background-color: rgba(50, 173, 140, 0.82);
}

/****
SOCIAL
****/

.insta {
    height: 50px;
    width: 90%;
    background-color: blue;
    margin: 10px auto;
}



/****
FOOTER
****/

.footer {
    background-color: grey;
    height: 100px;
    clear: both;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

.footer p {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/skeleton.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  </head>

  <body>
  
          <ul class="navigation six columns offset-by-three">
              <li><a href="#" style="color: #009999">HOME</a></li>
              <li><a href="portfolio.html" class="submenu">PORTFOLIO</a>
                  <div class="sub-hover">
                    <a href="portfolio/photo.html">Photos</a>
                    <a href="portfolio/physical.html">Physical</a>
                    <a href="portfolio/write.html">Write</a>
                    <a href="portfolio/studies.html">Studies</a>
                  </div>
              </li>
              <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
              <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
          </ul>
      
      <div id="logo">
        <div class="circle">
        </div>
      </div>
    
    <div class="main-gallery eleven columns offset-by-half">
          <div id="main-images">
            <img src=""/>
            <img src=""/>
            <img src=""/>
            <img src=""/>
          </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="testimonial">
        <div class="test-text">          
            <p><b>Joe Blogs</b></p>
            <p>Distinguished Person</p>
            <p><i>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas et orci sit amet nibh aliquam auctor eu eget turpis. Quisque quis leo lacus. Etiam vitae magna eu arcu gravida tincidunt. Ut consectetur mi id enim."</i></p>
        </div>
    </div>
      
    <div class="divide"></div>
      
    <div class="insta">
        
        
    </div>
      
    <div class="footer twelve columns">
        <p>Jacob Riman Design</p>
      
    </div>
    
  </body>
  
</html>
```

Comment: Oh yes I know, I've taken it away as it wasn't doing anything. changing the padding to '5px 5%', did exactly the same as changing it to '9px 5%'. It seems to be something else that is causing the issue.

Comment: I'm not seeing this at all. The padding increases when I change it, which I can see for certain using the chrome dev tools. What browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
.testimonial {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 0 5% 5% 0;
    background-color: rgba(50, 173, 140, 0.82);
}
```

Adding all of the values ( even if 0 ) solved the problem right away.

Also, I am aware that if only two values are given the 1st represents top and bottom.